# Stop rendering template in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, ajax, handlebars.js, expression

I have this small code that gets rendered the first time the page loads.

```
<div id="old-div">
  <h2>{{description}}</h2>
  <h2>{{example}}</h2>
</div>
```

Now the second time, an AJAX call happens and since first time the {{description}} and {{example}} are already filled, when i try to get the HTML of the template, instead of {{description}} and {{example}}, i get their values.

I don't want Handlebars to render the values to the expression when ajax call happens to that i can get the template and render new values.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a template, put it outside html `<body>` and use *that* to feed handlebars. You will be able to take it, feed handlebars and append to DOM with substituted values *and* retrieve the template itself (you can use `<template>` tag for it or `<script>` and add `id` attribute to reference it easily. That's how it's done on many websites.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have a separate handlebar `div` for compilation purpose and use that compiled HTML to append in your appropriate `div` so that you don't override your handlebar code in HTML.